# comapre two file and print only matching content

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I have two files file1 and file2.

file1 content:

```
fc1/20 20:64:00:2a:6a:7d:c8:81
fc1/19 20:b0:00:25:b5:ff:11:02
fc1/18 20:b0:00:25:b5:ff:11:09
fc1/17 20:b0:00:25:b5:ff:11:0b
fc1/16 20:b0:00:25:b5:ff:11:0d
```

file2 content:

```
20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0D prd-vm32
20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0D prd-vm32
20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0B prd-vm30.bred
20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0B prd-vm30.bred
50:06:0B:00:00:C2:62:1D PRD-VM16
50:06:0B:00:00:C2:62:1F PRD-VM16
50:06:0B:00:00:C3:4E:1D prd-vm07
50:06:0B:00:00:C3:4E:1F prd-vm07
```

I want output should be like mentioned below:

```
fc1/16 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0D prd-vm32
fc1/17 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0B prd-vm30.bred
```

Please let me know, how can I achieve the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to explain exactly what you want this program to return, as it's not entirely clear from the question and it's vital for understanding your problem.

Comment: So you want to merge the lines based on the MAC address and then only show the distinct lines that have been merged? Lines that have not been merged are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

`join(1)` suffers from a sorting necessity problem; stashing the keys into a hash avoids this (at the cost of greater memory use).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %by_mac;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV; # TODO usage notes if not set
open my $f1, '<', $file1;    # TODO error checking on open
open my $f2, '<', $file2;    # TODO error checking on open

while (my $line = readline $f1) {
  chomp $line;
  my @col = split ' ', $line;
  $by_mac{ lc $col[1] }->[0] = $col[0];
}
while (my $line = readline $f2) {
  chomp $line;
  my @col = split ' ', $line;
  $by_mac{ lc $col[0] }->[1] = $col[1];
}

#use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%by_mac;

for my $key (keys %by_mac) {
  if ( grep(defined, @{ $by_mac{$key} }) == 2 ) {
    say join " ", $by_mac{$key}->[0], $key, $by_mac{$key}->[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[toupper($2)]=$1;next}
($1 in arr){print arr[$1],$0;delete arr[$1]}' file1 file2
```

FNR: The ordinal number of the current record in the current file.

NR: The ordinal number of the current record from the start of input.

next: skips the line processing and continues at next line.

While reading the first line, FNR=NR. Store first column($1) into array arr with index uppercase second field ($2) and skip to next line.

While processing second file, loop through the array elements.
If $1 of second file is in array elements, print array value and line from second file. Delete the array element to skip the duplicates.

Comment: [root@fiscsec tmp]# awk 'FNR==NR{arr[toupper($2)]=$1;next} ($1 in arr){print arr[$1],$0;delete arr[$1]}' file1 file2
fc1/13 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:22:01 prd-db583031.
fc1/15 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:07 prd-vm26.
fc1/16 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0D prd-vm32
fc1/16 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:02 prd-vm21.brew
fc1/13 20:B0:00:25:B5:FF:11:0C prd-vm31.brew

Comment: Glad that it worked. Can you accept this answer if it helped?